# Adding field to the auth_user_group intermediatary table

Tags: django, authentication, user-management

Does anyone know if it is possible to add a field to the intermediatary auth_user_group table? I'd like to have a manager flag to identify a user that is a member of a group as a group manager (the permissions for this will be handled separately), but this relationship seems obfuscated by Django.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably create a GroupManager model to handle this.

```
class UserGroupManager(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, limit_choices_to={'groups__name': "some-group"})
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
```

Comment: Thanks Gustavo. I have implemented something similar. It is a shame that Django abstracts the User <-> Group ManyToMany relationship away in the PermissionMixin, as subclassing and overriding this can become quite hacky and complicated!